# getting a module not found error when trying to save my particles

Tags: particles

i'm trying to add particles.js npm to my project, i was able to download the package successfully, however, when i'm adding the script to my App.js and save i'm getting the following error message
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js 53:14-62

Module not found: Error: Package path ./Plugins/PolygonMask/Enums is not exported from package C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles (see exports field in C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles\package.json)

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js 482:14-42

Module not found: Error: Package path ./Enums is not exported from package C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles (see exports field in C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles\package.json)

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js 484:14-60

Module not found: Error: Package path ./Plugins/Absorbers/Enums is not exported from package C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles (see exports field in C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles\package.json)

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js 486:14-59

Module not found: Error: Package path ./Plugins/Emitters/Enums is not exported from package C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles (see exports field in C:\Users\mekstein\Desktop\facerecognition\node_modules\tsparticles\package.json)

this is my js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';

const particlesOptions = {
  particles: {
    line_linked: {
      shadow: {
        enable: true,
        color: "#3CA9D1",
        blur: 5
      }
    }
  }
  
}

  

class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Particles 
              params={particlesOptions}
            />
       <Navigation />
       <Logo />
       <Rank />
       <ImageLinkForm />
       {/*<FaceRecognition />*/}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a deprecation notice on `react-particles-js` here: https://github.com/wufe/react-particles-js#warning-deprecation-notice

Migrate to `react-particles` instead (it's just the new naming for `react-tsparticles` specified in the deprecation notice): https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/tree/main/components/react